# What's the best way to draw gizmos in build

Tags: unity, rendering, gui, unity-ui

I currently use Unity gizmos for many debugging purposes, but I'd like almost all of them to be visible to the player in-game (when the game is built).

For example, when a player is dragging to place a wall along a grid, I use Gizmos.DrawCube.

I know of a couple of options:

1. ALINE - an asset on Unity asset store, but currently doesn't work with 2D Experimental URP
2. Line renderer - seems very manual and tedious to do, and I'm unsure how I could modify it using code
3. Placing pictures as UI elements over selected tiles (seems pretty expensive to do?)

Any suggestions are appreciated!

Comment: I don't think you'll find an objective "best" here. All the ways you can describe and more can work and perform adequately. The real question is which one you prefer working with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gizmos are for development, not for playing. The usual approach to implement a gizmo would be to create a gameObject representing said gizmo which you activate and deactivate as needed.

So instead of:

```
if (isDragging) {
     Gizmos.DrawCube(dragPosition, dragSize);
}
```

You write:

```
if (isDragging) {
     myGizmo.SetActive(true);
     myGizmo.transform.position = dragPosition;
     myGizmo.transform.scale = dragSize;
} else {
     myGizmo.SetActive(false);
}
```

While this seems a bit more convoluted, think of all the possibilities you have when your gizmos are full-fledged gameObjects which can have any kind of visual and logical components you want.

Comment: Would the gizmo GameObject represent an image? How would I go about achieving something similar to this (recorded in Rimworld): https://gifyu.com/image/DuJ5
Would a selection box for each square be a separate GO, or is there a way to repeat the texture only using one GO?

Comment: @franticabyss You could probably do that with one sprite renderer which uses *Draw Mode: Tiled*. In that case you would not change `transform.scale` to control the size but instead change the width and height of the SpriteRenderer component.

Comment: Thanks! I've got a good general idea of how to do this now - just one more question. How would I make it so that if I'm dragging a line of where a wall is supposed to be placed, and some part of that wall is over an obstacle, I either don't draw the squares or draw them with red color? Using a single sprite renderer wouldn't work for that. Have you maybe got any ideas?

Comment: @franticabyss In that case you would have to use multiple game objects. Or perhaps you could pull it off with some shader magic. But when you never wrote a shader before, better stick to game objects,